# RStudio -> How can I combine multiple True/False variables into a single categorical variable?

Tags: r, binary, case, mutate, categorical

Trying to change raw data to categorical groups that can be used in analysis.

Data to look like this [image]

```
df=df %>%
  mutate(
    Swedish=factor(Swedish, levels=c("Checked", "Unchecked")
)

NEWdf$Country=df %>%
  case_when(
      Swedish="Checked"~"Swedish", 
      #ect for other Nationalities, 
      .default="Other"
  )
```

Comment: Using R, setting up a database :)

Comment: try to use dput() to give us data example and show the unwanted result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it should be inside a mutate

```
library(dplyr)
# Example data
df <- data.frame(
  Swedish = sample(c("Checked", "Unchecked"), 10, replace =  TRUE)
)
df=df %>%
  mutate(
    Swedish=factor(Swedish, levels=c("Checked", "Unchecked"))
)

df = df %>%
mutate(country = 
  case_when(
      Swedish == "Checked" ~ "Swedish", 
      TRUE ~ "Other"
  )
)
df
```

output

```
     Swedish country
     1    Checked Swedish
     2  Unchecked   Other
     3  Unchecked   Other
     4  Unchecked   Other
```